How to Calculate Optimal Input Amount for Arbitrage in V3 Pool
I'm looking to optimize my arbitrage strategy involving V3 pools . Specifically, I want to determine the most efficient input amount of tokens to maximize profit.
Could you provide guidance or point me towards resources that explain how to calculate the optimal input amount for an arbitrage trade in a V3 pool?
Thank you!
